# Convert characters to dates without having some of them as NAs after the convertion

Tags: r, date

I have those data

```
    sg2<-structure(list(`Last prescription/or progression time (if progressed)` = c("23-11-2021", 
"28-09-2022", "45020", "45079", "23-05-2023"), time = c(3.682191781, 
9.008219178, 22.52054795, 20.02191781, 12.7890411), status = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `Number of bone lesions (<5 = “<5”, >=5 = “≥5”) (clear, multiple bone metastases ≥5 are defined)` = c(">=5", 
"<5", ">=5", ">=5", "<5")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and some my dates data are displayed as 44383 for example while other dates are loaded normally from my excel file. I try to convert them all to dates below but then I get dates as NAs

```
sg2$`Time of first prescription of denosumab (if enrolled in QL1206 and JMT, this time is the time of first use of XGEVA after leaving the group)` <- as.Date(as.numeric(sg2$`Time of first prescription of denosumab (if enrolled in QL1206 and JMT, this time is the time of first use of XGEVA after leaving the group)`), origin = "1899-12-30")
Warning message:
In as.Date(as.numeric(sg2$`Time of first prescription of denosumab (if enrolled in QL1206 and JMT, this time is the time of first use of XGEVA after leaving the group)`),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
sg2 %>% rename('col1' =1) %>% mutate(col11= ifelse(nchar(col1)==10, col1, NA),
                                               col11=as.Date(col11, tryFormats='%d-%m-%Y'),
                                               col12= ifelse(nchar(col1)==5, col1, NA),
                                               col12= as.Date(as.numeric(col12), origin='1970-01-01'),
                                               col1=coalesce(col11,col12)
) %>% select(-c(col11, col12))


# A tibble: 5 × 4
  col1        time status Number of bone lesions (<5 = “<5”, >=5 = “≥5”) (clear, multiple bone metastases ≥5 are defin…¹
  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                                                                                         
1 2021-11-23  3.68      0 >=5                                                                                           
2 2022-09-28  9.01      0 <5                                                                                            
3 2093-04-05 22.5       0 >=5                                                                                           
4 2093-06-03 20.0       0 >=5                                                                                           
5 2023-05-23 12.8       0 <5                                                                                            
# ℹ abbreviated name:
#   ¹​`Number of bone lesions (<5 = “<5”, >=5 = “≥5”) (clear, multiple bone metastases ≥5 are defined)`
```

Comment: can you adapt like if I want to apply it on every column of my actual dataset that has dates separately? consider that there is not the 1st column like in my edited data

Comment: yes , you may , but i did not understand your question properly so may not provide the code unless you provide a dummy data

Comment: ok sorry i updated my sg2 dataset above as exactly is my actual so please apply any solution that may work

Comment: did u check it?

Comment: updated the answer please check